# Parsing json file: D:\Important\User\AppName\app\google-services.json Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I am having the error

```
Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: D:\Important\Dheeraj\Pukaar\app\google-services.json
```

When I run the application. I am Android Studio using 3.5 Canary 12 ( I am having some problem in stable release) . I tried to rebuild, invalidate and restart, restart my computer, replacing my google-services.json file but nothing works.

Full Build

```
> Configure project :app
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugApplicationId UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: D:\Important\Dheeraj\Pukaar\app\google-services.json

> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-alpha12-5342889-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-alpha12-5342889-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-alpha12-5342889-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-alpha12-5342889-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-alpha12-5342889-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-alpha12-5342889-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-alpha12-5342889-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-alpha12-5342889-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
14 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 10 up-to-date
```

Comment: The problem is not with parsing the JSON file.  That's just an informational message.  The error messages start with "Multiple task action failures occurred".  Later on it suggests for you to "try" something to get more info.

Comment: The problem is with the gradle version. I downgraded to   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'  and It's working properly now. Thanks you very much.